# Provblem with acessing Provider from a child widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, provider

I am having a problem with accessing the provider class from the child widget.

This is my Main.dart file.

```
...
home: MultiProvider(
        providers: [
          Provider<UserProvider>(
            create: (context) => UserProvider(),
          ),
          Provider<InvetoryProvider>(
            create: (context) => InvetoryProvider(),
          ),
        ],
        child: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (context, userSnapshot) {
            if (userSnapshot.hasData) return LoadingWidget(userSnapshot);
            return Login();
          },
        ),
      ),
...
```

I initialized `InvetoryProvider` class in main.dart I want to access this in `MyInventoryScreen`. My widget tree some thing looks like this.

```
-MaterialApp 
 -LoadingScreen
  -HomeScreen
   -MyUsersScreen
   -MyInventoryScreen
 -LoginScreen
```

I tried to access InventoryProvider in `MyInventoryScreen`, But it showing me huge error.

```
 var inventoryProvider = Provider.of<InvetoryProvider>(context);
```

Is it even possible to penetrate that deep with Provider? it works file if wrap `MyInventoryScreen`.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Looks correct to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want a provider to be accessible in all of your app's screens, you need to put that provider above your `MaterialApp` widget.

Comment: Thanks man! That really helped. No one really mentioned this point in any of the tutorials I've watched. Have a nice day!!

Comment: You're welcome! So happy it was helpful :D. Thanks, You too!